# hql - how to populate a child entity's lazy collection when fetching the parent

Tags: hibernate, jpql

suppose i have @Entity A, which has an eager @ManyToOne to @Entity B, and this B has a lazy (default) @OneToMany to a collection called "images"

i want to do something like:

```
"select a from A a join fetch a.b.images where a.b = :b"
```

this is a query that finds an instance of A given an instance of B (the A-->B link is unidirectional from A).
trying something like the above approach lands me a hibernate exception:

```
query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

but trying something like

```
"select a, a.b.images from ..."
```

will return multiple results for every instance of A (multiplied by the amount of images)

how do i write a query on A that populates a.b.images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - you first need to join fetch a.b assign an alias and then join fetch alias.images. Check [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) for more details. It would not be a good idea to do this if a.b and b.images are both one-to-many - it will lead to a result set explosion.  Something like batch-size or sub-select would be a better way to optimize it.

```
"select a from A a join fetch a.b x join fetch x.images where a.b = :b"
```